# Pandas_datareader: how to download the price data of "stock symbol with non-alphabetic symbol"?

Tags: pandas, stock, pandas-datareader

With normal symbols such as `AAPL, MSFT, AMZN`,

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web

df = web.DataReader('AAPL', "yahoo")
```

works well.

But with symbols with a non-alphabetic symbol such as`'GDV$G', 'GEF.B', 'GGN$B', 'GGO$A', 'GGP$A'`, above code doesn't work.

How can I download the price data of them?